# Yii2 lajax/yii2-translate-manager or lajax/yii2-language-picker PHP8.1 throws errors

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am using lajax/yii2-translate-manager and lajax/yii2-language-picker
After server upgrade to PHP version 8.1 switching to another language throws an error

```
An Error occurred while handling another error:
ValueError: setcookie(): "path" option cannot contain ",", ";", " ", "\t", "\r", "\n", 
"\013", or "\014" in /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Response.php:404
Stack trace:
#0 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Response.php(404): setcookie()
#1 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Response.php(381): yii\web\Response->sendCookies()
#2 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Response.php(339): yii\web\Response->sendHeaders()
#3 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/ErrorHandler.php(135): yii\web\Response->send()
#4 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/ErrorHandler.php(111): yii\web\ErrorHandler- 
   >renderException()
#5 [internal function]: yii\base\ErrorHandler->handleException()
#6 {main}
Previous exception:
ValueError: setcookie(): "path" option cannot contain ",", ";", " ", "\t", "\r", "\n", 
"\013", or "\014" in /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Response.php:404
Stack trace:
#0 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Response.php(404): setcookie()
#1 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Response.php(381): yii\web\Response->sendCookies()
#2 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Response.php(339): yii\web\Response->sendHeaders()
#3 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(392): yii\web\Response->send()
#4 /app/frontend/web/index.php(17): yii\base\Application->run()
#5 {main}
```

I see that there is some cookie issue but dont know what causes this and how to fix this. Maby someone have atleast idea what to look for?

Comment: I recommend you provide more details. What cookie are you attempting to set? Give us a *similar* sample (don't post real world credentials). Seems like the error is pretty explicit. You can't have a cookie with a path containing those characters. Is this a Wordpress website? Wordpress has plenty of documentation on these `setCookie` exceptions when upgrading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution - there is new approach how to set language cookie in Yii2 newest version. In frontend(or backend - where you are using Yii2 lajax/yii2-translate-manager) -> components -> LanguageSelector.php need to rewrite code

```
    class LanguageSelector implements BootstrapInterface
{
    public $supportedLanguages = [];

    /**
     * @param Application $app
     */
    public function bootstrap($app)
    {
        // ignore lang parameter if language picker has been selected
        if (!empty($app->request->get('language-picker-language'))) {
            $languageCookie = new Cookie([
                'name' => 'language',
                'value' => $app->request->get('language-picker-language'),
                'expire' => strtotime('+30 days'),
                'path' => '/',
                'secure' => true,
                'sameSite' => 'None', //Select: Lax, None or Strict
            ]);
            $app->response->cookies->add($languageCookie);
            return;
        }

        // get language from request
        $preferredLanguage = $app->request->get('lang');

        if (strlen($preferredLanguage) === 2) {
            $preferredLanguage .= '-' . strtoupper($preferredLanguage);
        }

        if (!empty($preferredLanguage)) {
            $languageCookie = new Cookie([
                'name' => 'language',
                'value' => $preferredLanguage,
                'expire' => strtotime('+30 days'),
                'path' => '/',
                'secure' => true,
                'sameSite' => 'None', ////Select: Lax, None or Strict
            ]);
            $app->response->cookies->add($languageCookie);
        }

        // get language from cookie
        if (empty($preferredLanguage)) {
            $preferredLanguage = isset($app->request->cookies['language']) ? $app->request->cookies['language']->value : null;
        }

        // get language from browser
        if (empty($preferredLanguage)) {
            $preferredLanguage = $app->request->getPreferredLanguage(array_keys(Language::getLanguageNames(true)));
        }

        $app->language = $preferredLanguage;
    }
}
```